# Get next all items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of items.

```
var array = [box1, box2, box3, box4];
```

when item is **box1**, i need to get **box2, box3, box4**.

when item is **box2**, get **box3, box4**

how to get next all items with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you don't need jquery though. Just use `Array.slice` to get everything from supplied index to the end:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(x.slice(1)); // [2, 3, 4]
console.log(x.slice(2)); // [3, 4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do that:

```
var array = [box1, box2, box3, box4];

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++){

     var 
         box1 = array[i],
         box2 = array[i + 1],
         box3 = array[i + 2],
         box4 = array[i + 3];

}
```